# Composer outdated shows drupal/core has a newer version, but composer update says "nothing to update"

Tags: drupal-8

This is similar to an unanswered question from a year ago. Supposedly I have an update for drupal/core:

```
$ composer outdated "drupal/*"
drupal/core                     8.6.10       8.6.12       Drupal is an open source content ...
```

But when I run update ...

```
$ composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
Dependency "asm89/stack-cors" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "composer/semver" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
[ ... ]
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

I'm trying to follow the instructions to update drupal 8 via composer found here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today with updating Drupal and the following process helped me solve the issue.

- Run the composer update command using the specific version you are trying to update to.  In this instance it would be `composer require drupal/core:8.6.12 --update-with-dependencies`  If there is an issue blocking the update this should show you a list of problems.  in my case I tried to update to version 8.6.11 and it output the following.

> Problem 1
>
> . Installation request for drupal/core 8.6.11 -> satisfiable by
>   drupal/core[8.6.11].
>
> . Can only install one of: twig/twig[1.x-dev, v1.35.3].
>
> . Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.3, 1.x-dev].
>
> . Can only install one of: twig/twig[1.x-dev, v1.35.3].
>
> . drupal/core 8.6.11 requires twig/twig ^1.38.2 -> satisfiable by
>   twig/twig[1.x-dev, v1.38.2].
>
> . Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.38.2
>
> . Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.35.3, required as
>   ^1.35.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.3].

- If there is no problem listed try clearing the composer cache `composer clearcache` and then try the update command again.
- you can also try running the why-not composer command to see if that highlights any issues `composer why-not drupal/core:8.6.12`

In my case the issue was that the twig component required for 8.6.12 was v1.38.2 but was capped at a lower version 1.35 in the composer file.  I used the following command to update the twig version and that allowed me to update to Drupal 8.6.12 using my normal update process.

```
composer require twig/twig:1.35.2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bevan! I was a bit of an idiot when I didn't read the rest of the "update" article. I ran "composer prohibits" and discovered the twig dependency.